# How to extract wav file into array in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I need to read the wav file which is one dimensional array audio sample.

I need to plot wav audio file into graph.

I tried fs npm,wav npm.I could able to extract the buffer data from wav file like 
then converted into array using

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer, 0);

var buffer = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer, 0);
```

I got array of data.I found something went wrong when comparing with original signal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this module [tone-generator](https://github.com/karlwestin/node-tonegenerator).

Comment: Thank You for valuable suggestion.I can able to extract the wav file using wav-decoder.